# Wrong behavior with autoSizeMode

Tags: codenameone

I've problem with autoSizeMode enabled for some labels while rotating screen.

It appears only when I first start the app in portrait and rotate to landscape (no problem with landscape first then portrait).

Portrait, "06/07/2017" is fully visible :

[image: before rotate]

Then, after rotation, "06/07/2017" not fully visible :

[image: after rotation]

Comment: There seems to be a bug with the autosize functionality and rotation, can you please file an issue in the issue tracker and we'll try to get to it.

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2152